# Spring's Javaconfig and Prototyped Beans

Tags: java, spring

I've moved my code from Spring's XML configuration to Java Configuration. I have everything working, but I have a question about how I implemented prototype beans - mainly, while what I'm doing works, is it the best way to do this? Somehow it just feels off!

I wrote the bean class this way:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ProtoBean {
    ...
}
```

Then to use the bean - this is the part that I'm just not sure about, although it does work:

```
@Component
public class BeanUser implements ApplicationContextAware {
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)throws BeansException
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void getProtoBean() {
         ProtoBean protoBean = context.getBean(ProtoBean.class);
    }
}
```

This gets me a prototyped bean, and in unit tests I just mocked the context, called setApplicationContext with the mock, and had the getBean call of the mock return a mock ProtoBean. So all is well.

I did this in the XML by using a factory, but that didn't seem to work too well, so this is where I ended up. But is there a way to do this without the context? Or just a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using a Java-based configuration at this point. Have a look here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java

Comment: That's an interesting link - thank you. I am using @ComponentScan to pick this up in my java config class, so it pretty much seems to work out the same way, and interestingly this matches the first example they give of how to do this in your link - but then they go on to talk about "method injection" which seems to be their suggested solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is so much an issue of Spring XML vs Java-base configuration, but one of matching dependency scopes. Since Spring can only do dependency injection on the singleton-scoped bean at creation time, you have to lookup the prototype-scoped bean on demand. Of course the current bean-lookup approach works, but creates a dependency on the ApplicationContext. I can suggest a few other possibilities but the root of the issue is really what is involved in producing a ProtoBean, and what trade-offs should you accept.

You could make BeanUser itself prototype-scoped, which would allow you to wire in the ProtoBean as a member. Of course the trade-off is you now have the same problem on the clients of BeanUser, but sometimes that would not be a problem.

Another path could be using something like a singleton-scoped ProtoBeanFactory to provide ProtoBean instances, and hiding dependency lookups within the ProtoBeanFactory.

Finally, you could use a scoped-proxy bean to effectively hide the factory. It uses AOP to do this, and isn't always clear to others what sort of voodoo you have going.  With XML you'd use `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` on the bean declaration. For annotations you'd use:

```
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
```